# Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, memory, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas](https://superuser.com/questions/527196/excel-ran-out-of-resources-while-attempting-to-calculate-one-or-more-formulas)

I received the error message 
"Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas"
on **ONE** of my computers (Out of 2).

My worksheet contains: (Inside a single worksheet, not workbook, there are formulas in another worksheet)

- > 1,000,000 formulas
- a Pivot table base on 900,000 rows of data

When I run excel/vba on the action "Calculate Sheet" (The current worksheet only), the program would pop the following error message:

```
Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas
```

on neither I "refresh" a pivot table in (Excel or VBA)  or "Calculate Sheet" in (Excel or VBA)

I have 2 computers:

- both running 64 bits Windows 7,
- both running Excel 2007 32Bit,
- I run Excel right after starting Windows,
- my development PC with 2GB RAM can run without problem,
- another PC with 6GB RAM shown the `ran out of resources` error message
- Running on same set of data, same excel file

I also notice that on my development PC, it is using ~ 1.2G RAM, and the non-working PC, it is using 900M RAM prior to clicking the "Refresh"/"Calculate" Action.

**EDIT**

The Non-working Computer can handle data within 100,000 rows of data

**My questions:**

1. Why it is working for the computer with less memory but not the one with more memory? (main question)
2. What can I do to reduce the memory used by Excel? (sub question) (Other than deleting data)

Any help is appreciated, please point me into the right direction or simply give some clue.

**EDIT**:I am thinking of removing the formulas, and move the logic into vba, and do it by caching the data maybe per 10,000 rows. But this won't solve my problem if "refresh" pivot table would show the same error.